# Use of encrypting data in transit over a HTTPS connection

Tags: encryption, api

I find certain APIs (that provide sensitive information) using algorithms like `ECDHE` with `X25519`, *on top* of the already encrypted SSL connection. This compels us to use libraries like [Tink](https://github.com/google/tink) (when we have to use it in Android Apps) that provides such algorithms, though the classes it provides us for using such algorithms is explicitly marked not to be used in production.

Is there any reason this could have use cases when transmitting sensitive information?

Comment: Can you provide a reference to such an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason can be deployment structure of the applications. Many applications have a web server that is responsible for static resources only, and delegates dynamic requests to a separate application. Such web server is often a TLS/SSL termination point and the connection from this web server to the application remains not encrypted. In case one wants to ensure that data are encrypted on the whole way to the application, a separate encryption can be used, like what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Like @mentallurg said, it could be done to facilitate end-to-end encryption between the API client and the actual server intended to receive it.

I have also seen some applications that enable a mode like this when they are unable to negotiate a secure connection with certificate pinning (e.g. due to an intercepting proxy) and therefore cannot rely on HTTPS alone for confidentiality, but can still continue to function without degrading availability.

Another possible reason is that it may act as a deterrent to those who are trying to examine or possibly reverse engineer the API.